# cakephp: seo friendly url routing - avoid the url parameter passed

Tags: php, cakephp, seo, cakephp-routing

I am working hard to get my seo routing working. Right know I am able to build such url:

```
http://mydomain/Rentals
```

As soon as I need to use the pagination, I get urls like this

```
http://mydomain/Rentals/page:2?url=Rentals
```

I can't figure out what I have to do in order to avoid the url parameter?
Can I remove it somehow? It would be great if the url would look just like this:

```
http://mydomain/Rentals/page:2
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your htaccess file.
It should look like this:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/webroot/.htaccess

Note the `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` part.